# How to do search in B+tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, b-tree

Can someone explain how search is done in a B+ tree? The confusing thing for me is that in comparison with a B-tree, B+tree doesn't hold data in internal nodes, only in leaves. So for examples I have a B+-tree index build over a list of names. I want to find a name "Mary". The root key in a B+tree is 20. How should I compare "Mary" to 20, if 20 holds no data?

Comment: the "20" you mentioned is the key. Same idea, you have to have the key of "Mary" in order to search it.Otherwise it does not make any sense. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree

Comment: Exactly. But who in the hell is interested in key, a client wants to find "Mary"? How am I to find the key of "Mary" then?